# Chat Bot gets confused somehow

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

On IBM Watson chat bot, I have created 2 entities, one named as @serial_number and the other named as @material_number.

The pattern for serial number is `(\d{7,9})-(\d{2,4})-(\d{1,3})`
and the pattern for material number is `(\d{3}).(\d{3}).(\d{3}).(\d{3})`.

In "welcome" node, the bot asks for the name of the user and in the node below if the bot recognizes the name, it then also searches for other types of input. I want the bot to be able to capture both serial and material numbers from the input. Therefore I have activated the slots mode, then added 2 slots with variables $serialnumber and $materialnumber. For both their values I have used the "literal" function, so that the bot can store the input of the user into the context variables.

When there is an input such as "Hello, I am Henrik. I have a pen. Its serial number is 1234567-123-12 and its material number is 123.123.123.123", the respond of the bot is as the following:

> "Okay, the serial number is 1234567-123-12"
>
> "Okay, the material number is 1234567"

It captures the serial number correctly, according to the provided pattern. Yet, however it gets the material number wrong. The material number it should capture is **123.123.123.123**, but it captures **1234567** even if among the provided patterns for the @material_number there exists no such pattern.

I, somehow, need to make the bot capture the right thing.

I would be very happy if someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more information on how you capture it and how you generate the response? What is the code for it?

Comment: Hello @data_henrik, so the bot captures it using the context variables. For serial number, I have a variable $serialnumber with the value "<?@serial_number.literal?>" and for the material number I have a variable $materialnumber with the value "<?@material_number.literal?>". When the bot recognizes sys-person, it also searches for both material and serial number within the same input. If it finds the numbers, it responds like the following: Your material number is blablabla and your serial number is blabla. But as I said it just confuses the numbers and I dont really understand why.

Comment: please edit your question and format the code pieces

Comment: Hello @data_henrik, do you want screenshots or? Couldn´t quite understand what you mean by "edit your question". Thank you !

Comment: There is an "edit" button below the question. You can use it to move details from comments into the question. So it is now necessary to read over all the comments to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @data_henrik , I have edited it. Please help me if you know a way.

Comment: What is the text that produces the response? There are variables inside. Show the full code.

Answer (score 1):

This is because a `.` in a regular expression matches any character. If you want to specify a literal `.` you will need to escape it in the expression. ie.

```
(\d{3})\.(\d{3})\.(\d{3})\.(\d{3})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, appreciate it. I could not get it completely to be honest. Can you clarify what you mean ?

Comment: (\d{3})\.(\d{3})\.(\d{3})\.(\d{3})